# Need a formula for the SUM of a range of cells, but ONLY IF a different cell outside of that range has a date in it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, sumifs, openoffice-calc

I've done some searching but could not find what I need, so I hope one of you kind souls can help.

I have a spreadsheet that someone set up for me a few years ago and I eventually set aside.  Now I want to use it again and I am finding that I want to change some things, but I have very basic Excel skills.

I am tracking payments received for contract/gig work.  I have more columns than this, but for simplicity's sake, I'll say I am working with columns for **Fees**, **Bonuses**, **Date Paid**, and then **Total Rec'd**.

When I schedule an assignment, the data goes across the rows.  I enter the Company I'm doing work for, the date of the assignment, a name for it, and then the agreed-upon contract amounts for Fees and Bonuses. When I am paid, anywhere from 2 weeks to 3 months later, I enter the date in the Date Paid column.

What I need is for the *total at the end of each row*, under the **Total Paid** heading, to SUM the figures *in that row* from **Fees** and **Bonuses** ONLY IF there is a date *in that row* under the **Date Paid** heading.

If there's **no date** (meaning I have not gotten paid yet), I'd want the cells in the last column to be **blank or zero**.  That would help me see who has paid me yet or not (the companies all have different pay cycles and the dollar amounts are not huge, so a missed payment can easily go unnoticed).

Basically, as an example:

```
  A           B        C            D              E
Company      Fee      Bonus       Date Paid      Total Rec'd  
 ABC Co      $20       $10       08/09/2022        $30  
 EFG Co.     $40       $5        08/10/2022        $45  
 XYZ Co.     $20       $5                           0  
 KLM Co.     $30       $12       08/12/2022        $42
```

So, maybe a SUMIFS kind of thang?  So, in my example above, IF a date is entered *in a row under the column D heading*, then *in that row under Column E* I want the *SUM of the figures from the cells in columns B + C*. But *IF the Date Paid cell is blank, do not SUM*, or leave it as zero, or blank.

Does this all make sense how I explained it?  Oh, and by the way, in case it makes a difference, I'm using Open Office Calc.

Thanks in advance for any insight or help you can offer!

Comment: Try sumifs like `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">" & DATE(1900,1,1))`

Comment: @Harun24hr wow, that was fast.  Thank you.  But can you explain the formula you posted?  Like I said, my skills are very basic.

Comment: Check my answer. If it solve your problem then accept it (tick mark the answer).

Comment: I figured out how to do it but in a different way.  It was much easier than I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SUMIFS()` with date criteria so that it only sum those cells having  dates to adjacent column. Use-

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">" & DATE(1900,1,1))
```

Above formula will check every cell of B column and if it find any cell that have date greater than `01/01/1900`, it will sum values from column A.

Comment: where do I indicate in the formula which column is the date column?

Comment: @geox in replace of `B:B` column.

Comment: This is not making sense to me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in your E column and use this in E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;B2:B+C2:C))
```

[image]

additionally if you want E4 to be 0:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;IF(D2:D=""; 0; B2:B+C2:C)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @player0 - this looks good, but I'm getting errors when I try it.  Would you mind explaining what each part of the formula should represent?

Comment: @geox what says the error? not sure whats there to explain tho... "IF( column A is empty do nothing otherwise sum column B with column C)" that's pretty much it

Comment: Thank you.  The errors I got were ?NAME and then when I tried again, ?VALUE, I believe.  I had to change the cell numbers to mine, of course.  What's confusing me is the A2:A and D2:D.  Why is the first cell specified in the first part (A2 and D2) but only the column specified in the second (A and D)?

Comment: I also do not know why Column A is in the formula when that is the company name.

Comment: @geox see the explanation here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FQGdPQU6L7KyScljy9hTY97zYyRy_gq0oPgyAmAB7GE/edit#gid=2130870868

Comment: I figured out how to do it but in a different way. It was much easier than I thought it was.  Thanks anyway!